# How to rename multiple directories into corresponding file names in bash

Tags: regex, bash, for-loop, if-statement, file-rename

I need some help with bash script about rename directory:

I want to rename six directories first in order to conduct analysis:

this is original directory name for rename:

```
MCIA-1-control_20170509
MCIA-2-control_20170509
MCIA-03-timesport_20170717
MCIA-04-timesport_20170717
MCIA-05-timesport_20170717
MCIA-6-timesport_20170717
```

I need to rename as following:

```
subj-1-control
subj-2-control
subj-3-timesport
subj-4-timesport
subj-5-timesport
subj-6-timesport
```

I already declared several variables as below:

```
$fnIDs #e.g.MCIA-1-control_20170509... 
$ren #e.g. 1-control...
$raw_dir #data directory
```

then I run this loop, but the results did not as my expect:

```
for fn in ${fnIDs}; do 
    echo "+++this is all folder name for rename: fnIDs:${fnIDs}+++"
    echo "+++renameing folder: fn:${fn}+++"

    for rn in ${ren}; do
        echo "=======ADD "subj" to rename the subj folder==========="
        refn=subj-"$rn" #e.g. subj-1-control...
        echo "refn:$refn"
        echo "rename folder $fn to $refn"

        if ( test -d "$raw_dir"/"$fn"); then #if dir exist then
            cp -R "$raw_dir"/"$fn" "$raw_dir"/"$refn" #copy and rename file
            echo "cp rename the subj folder:$raw_dir/$refn"
        elif ( test -d "$raw_dir"/"$refn");then
            echo "++++++renamed subject folder already exists+++++++"           
        else
            echo "+++++somthing went wrong!Name of subject folder does not exists check "$fn $refn"+++++++++"
            exit
        fi
    done
done
```

**when I execute above script, they doing things as below:**

```
+++renameing folder: fn:MCIA-1-control_20170509+++
=======rename the subj folder===========
renfn:subj-1-control
rename folder MCIA-1-control_20170509 to subj-1-control
rename folder MCIA-1-control_20170509 to subj-2-control
```

**What I want to do is:**

```
rename folder MCIA-1-control_20170509 to subj-1-control
rename folder MCIA-2-control_20170509 to subj-2-control...
```

Basically, it rename original folder name into six different subj folder name...
I got stuck here for a while...

Thanks for help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using bash regular expression matching with capturing groups.

### Code

```
read -r -d '' input <<END
MCIA-0-control_20170509
MCIA-1-control_20170509
MCIA-2-control_20170509
MCIA-03-timesport_20170717
MCIA-04-timesport_20170717
MCIA-05-timesport_20170717
MCIA-6-timesport_20170717
END

for name in $input; do
    [[ $name =~ ^MCIA-0*([[:digit:]]+)-(control|timesport)_[[:digit:]]+$ ]] &&
            echo mv "$name" "subj-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

### Output

```
mv MCIA-0-control_20170509 subj-0-control
mv MCIA-1-control_20170509 subj-1-control
mv MCIA-2-control_20170509 subj-2-control
mv MCIA-03-timesport_20170717 subj-3-timesport
mv MCIA-04-timesport_20170717 subj-4-timesport
mv MCIA-05-timesport_20170717 subj-5-timesport
mv MCIA-6-timesport_20170717 subj-6-timesport
```

### Explanation

- `^`: Match start of string.
- `MCIA-`: Match the current directory prefix.
- `0*`: Optionally match any number of leading zeroes.  These do not go into a capturing group, because we want to discard them.
- `([[:digit:]]+)`: After discarding leading zeroes, capture one or more remaining digits into the first capture group.
- `-`: Match and discard the additional hyphen.
- `(control|timesport)`: Capture either "control" or "timesport" into the second capture group.
- `_[[:digit:]]+`: Match all the rest.
- `$`: Match end of string.

If the input string is a match, then build up the `mv` command with the destination as the concatenation of "subj", the first capture group and the second capture group.  For testing purposes, my code sample uses `echo` to print the command instead of running it.  You can expand as necessary with validation, existence checks, etc. as you are already doing in your original code sample.

For more details on regular expressions in bash, see [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide - 18.1. A Brief Introduction to Regular Expression](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach the problem is simply to add `-_` to `IFS` and separate each dirname into four components, add `subj-` to the beginning and use `$(())` to resolve/remove the leading zeros from the second component and then use the third unchanged, e.g. (for example purposes, I'm just reading your dirnames from a file, but you could use globbing or the `find` to provide them to the while loop), e.g.

```
$ cat dirs.txt
MCIA-1-control_20170509
MCIA-2-control_20170509
MCIA-03-timesport_20170717
MCIA-04-timesport_20170717
MCIA-05-timesport_20170717
MCIA-6-timesport_20170717
```

Then it's just a simple:

```
$ oifs="$IFS"; IFS="$IFS-_";   ## save old IFS, set new IFS
  while read -r dir; do        ## read each dirname
      arr=( $dir )             ## separate into array elements
      echo "mv $dir subj-$((${arr[1]}))-${arr[2]}"  ## use elements 1, 2
done < dirs.txt
IFS="$oifs"                    ## restore original IFS
mv MCIA-1-control_20170509 subj-1-control
mv MCIA-2-control_20170509 subj-2-control
mv MCIA-03-timesport_20170717 subj-3-timesport
mv MCIA-04-timesport_20170717 subj-4-timesport
mv MCIA-05-timesport_20170717 subj-5-timesport
mv MCIA-6-timesport_20170717 subj-6-timesport
```

To avoid using an array, you can do something similar to the following:

```
$ while read -r dir; do 
    echo $dir | 
    { IFS="$IFS-_"; read -r a b c d; echo "mv $dir subj-$((b))-$c"; }
done < dirs.txt
mv MCIA-1-control_20170509 subj-1-control
mv MCIA-2-control_20170509 subj-2-control
mv MCIA-03-timesport_20170717 subj-3-timesport
mv MCIA-04-timesport_20170717 subj-4-timesport
mv MCIA-05-timesport_20170717 subj-5-timesport
mv MCIA-6-timesport_20170717 subj-6-timesport
```